# Number of times the names of the husband & wife appear on the Ketubah

Tags: minhag, wedding, ketubah, maseches-kesubos, even-haezer

From a few Ketubot that I've seen, it seems that the husband's name is written 6x and the wife's name is written 3x.

- **Is there a specific number of times a husband's and wife's names should appear on the Ketubah?**  (and if so, when did this practice develop)
- Is there any significance re: the number of times the husband's  and wife's names are written on the Ketubah?

Comment: The ketubah is a Rabbinical freely worded agreement. I don't recall any "Kabbalistic" meaning of it. What would make you think that the number of mentions is important?

Comment: How many different versions of Ketubos did you compare?

Comment: @AlBerko where did I use the word “kabbalistic?”